# Former employer could not give certificate of employment

Tags: new-job, applications, employer-relations, harassment, philippines

I've got a new job coming right up. Only thing is, my former employer could not give me my COE.

I've emailed them, texted them, Skyped them that I need it soon. I've also been very clear, that I can wait for my back pay. I told them I just need my COE first.

However, same as last time with my salary, they are not responding to my messages. My calls could not reach their numbers.

Having a COE isn't really required to apply for a company if you just resigned from the last one.

All of us former employees have this problem with our sad excuse of a boss. Not just me.

I don't understand. How could an employer not be able to print and sign some documents? If they're planning to tell everyone I've never been employed by them they're gonna have a hard time explaining that because I have internal knowledge of their projects, my colleagues have given me their references, and my prospective employers believe us.

The alternative is I don't declare my experience with my former employer. I can't remove my experience with them from my resume, however, because that will leave a five month gap in my resume.

How do I approach the situation please?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Has the new employer demanded you present his COE? If not, what is the problem?

Comment: You should also [edit] your question regarding *could*. **Can** they not give it, do they **say** they can not give it, **won't** they give it - what exactly is going on?

Comment: I am not sure what a COE is used for but it sounds like a P45 that we have in Ireland (Document outlining what you've earned, tax you've paid, etc.). Is it possible that you weren't "on the books" i.e. not officially employed by the company? - e.g. your employer might not have been paying your tax. That's what happened to me but luckily I was starting the new job in the new year so I didn't need it.

Comment: "My calls could not reach their numbers." - if email and telephone don't work, there is postal mail. Send the letter and give them a deadline to respond (e.g. Please respond by ...). This makes it clear you don't want to be ignored.

Comment: @colmde I just heard that my employers are totally not paying any taxes--mine, the other employees, and their own. I'm glad I left them. They are unscrupulous businessmen and after the COE I just want to keep communication to the absolute minimum.

Comment: "My calls could not reach their numbers." - then they won't stay in business long. if no COE, and I fit is only used to check employment dates, could you show payslips?

Comment: "All of us former employees have this problem" - if there is a legal requirement to provide a COE, then threaten to report them if it is not forthcoming. In most countries you can get a free 30 to 60 minutes with a lawyer who will explain things if you agree that they will represent you if you proceed with a case. For you, just knowing the law might be enough. Otherwise, a few of you can split the lawyer's free to send a letter demanding the COEs and explaining the consequences, which should not cost too much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Document your employment through other means.**

You say yourself that you don't need a COE. [This legal forum](http://www.pinoylawyer.org/t14043-issuance-of-certificate-of-employment) seems to confirm that they have no legal obligation to provide one. That in turn *should* mean that an employer shouldn't require you to provide one or should allow you other ways to prove your employment if they're questioning your resume.

That same site suggests providing Social Security System payment confirmations as proof that you were employed. A commenter there claims that a company cannot refuse to prove that they've paid your SSS contributions. But take all that with a grain of salt.

If even that doesn't work and you don't want to start legal proceedings, you can use monthly or yearly pay stubs to prove that you were employed at a company.

But really, you shouldn't need to go to such lengths. You can talk about what you did at the employer and hiring managers don't typically require proof for every position you list on your resume as they normally assume good faith. I have no experience with hiring in the Phillipines but I doubt they do things that differently there.

Answer (score -3):

> If they're planning to tell everyone I've never been employed by them they're gonna have a hard time explaining that because I have internal knowledge of their projects, my colleagues have given me their references, and my prospective employers believe us.

No, they won't have a hard time you will. Releasing knowledge of internal projects of any company you worked with/for, is bound to bite you in the ass.

Why would any company hire you if you release sensitive information on the fly. Pick your fights, this one is not the one you want to pick since you clearly don't "need" the COE.